# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for a list

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class pGen_Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = 80;
        vGen(seed, (int) Math.pow(2, 32), 22695477, 1, 1);
    }
    private static void vGen(long x, long m, int a, int c, int p) {
        int area = (int) Math.pow(4, p-1);
        long y = 0;
        long[] tl = new long[area];
        double[] bl = new double[area*256];
        for(int i=0; i<area; i++) {
            x = (a*x+c)%m;
            tl[i] = x;
            for(byte j=0; j<256; j++) {
                if(j==0) y = (a*tl[i]+c)%m;
                else y = (a*y+c)%m;
                bl[256*i+j] = y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to write numbers to a list initialized for 256 items. After running the code, I receive an exception telling me that the index in bl[256*i+j] = y; has become -128. What should I do?

Comment: `(int) Math.pow(2, 32)` is a negative number when expressed as an int, I think.  So anything `% m` will also be negative.  Look up Two's Complement to understand why this works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Casting a `double` such as `Math.pow(2, 32)` that is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `int` will result in `Integer.MAX_VALUE`; you probably want to cast it as `long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Bytes are signed in Java, with a range of `-128` to `127`.  When `j` reaches its maximum value of `127` and is incremented, the value overflows and becomes `-128`.  Because you got a negative index, that means that `i` is still `0`.

To prevent this, change the datatype of `j` from `byte` to `int`.  There's no good reason that `j` should be a `byte`; array index expressions and mathematical expressions get promoted to `int` when evaluated anyway.  This will also allow `j` to reach `256` so that the loop will terminate.